# Basic calculus question about summation

Tags: calculus

I want to find $f(x)$ throught calculus, where $f(x) \equiv\sum_{i=1}^{x} i$

This is my reasoning:

let $ g(x) = x $, and $ \Delta x = \frac{1}{n}$ . Then, by Riemann integration,

$\sum_{i=0}^{x} i \sim \sum_{i=0}^{x} \frac{i}{n}·\frac{1}{n} \implies \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=0}^{x} \frac{i}{n}·\frac{1}{n} = \int_{0}^{x}x·dx =\frac{x^2}{2}$,

But Gauss found that

$\sum_{i=0}^{x}i = \frac{x^2+x}{2} $.

What part of the reasoning is false or bad developed?

Going backwards, knowing that

$F(x) = \frac{x^2+x}{2} $.

this function is the primitive of $f'(x) = x+\frac{1}{2}$, not just $x$.

Again, what is wrong? I love maths but i havent studied them in a high level, so if anyone could explain me I would be so grateful, thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

First, I have no idea what you are using $\sim$ to mean but on the left you have $0 + 1 + 2 + \dots + x$ and on the right you have $\frac{0}{n^2} + \frac{1}{n^2} + \dots + \frac{x}{n^2}$. While we're here: is $x$ an integer? Otherwise you should be more precise in what you mean. I also don't know what you are using the $\implies$ (implies) symbol to mean.

Secondly, if you take this sum $\frac{0}{n^2} + \frac{1}{n^2} + \dots + \frac{x}{n^2}$ and let $n \to \infty$ you get $0$ since each term goes to $0$.

Thirdly, writing $\int_0^x x \;dx$ is confusing because the variable inside the integral should not be the same variable use for the region of integration.

Comment: firstly, thanks for answering, and sorry for the confusing terms, as i said i have not studied mathematics properly.

Secondly, to understand my intentions, i have seen in more than a source people solves problems starting with a simplified version with the definition of integration, dividing integration domain into intervals delta x and summing each interval area (Delta x * f(x) ), and stating then that when intervals become infinitesimal the sum transforms into integration, and i wanted to try, but maybe  this can't be obtained with that approach.

Answer (score 0):

one really can solve some summation problems with integrals, but even your first statement $\Delta x=\frac{1}{n}$ is not valid if you wan a Riemann sum up to x or to a, better to choose a instead of the variable x then one has to choose $\Delta x=\frac{a}{n}$ the sum would then be $\sum_{i=0}^n\frac{ai}{n}*\frac{a}{n}\ne\sum_{i=0}^n i $
so your integral does not help you to find this sum

Answer (score 0):

One of the first things--among others--worth considering here is that, what appears to be the intended, *infinitesimal* element necessary for convergence is not very appropriate for the purposes of that *finite* series; although that pitfall is understandable.

But, as an addition to the replies so far, the most enlightening approach--short of a course on Real Analysis--might be to see a constructive proof of the method used to reach the correct answer.

So, to that end, here are some (hopefully appropriately elementary) resources:

Wikipedia's article on the [Euler-Maclaurin Forumla](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula) (and by extension: [Faulhaber's Polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula))
seems to contain a constructive proof--apparently due to Apostol's [“An Elementary View of Euler’s Summation Formula”](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2589145). They appear, at a glance, to be fairly approachable.

In addition, also are [Notes on Euler-Maclaurin](https://people.csail.mit.edu/kuat/courses/euler-maclaurin.pdf), which looked like good exposition. That in particular, also points to additional references, such as:
[Apostol (1973)](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ekrdavids/M148/Apostol.pdf) as well as an article on its [history](https://www.jstor.org/stable/41133762); worth noting, also, as an interesting aside, its [extension to singular functions](https://blog.wolfram.com/2021/06/30/the-singular-euler-maclaurin-expansion-a-new-twist-to-a-centuries-old-problem/)

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).